# CSS3 Grayscale filter on Android

Tags: android, html, css, cross-browser

I can't manage to apply a grayscale to an img on the android default browser.

Here's my CSS :

```
#solutions .grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}
```

Android is 2.3.5

Any idea on a way to apply a grayscale to an img that works on android phones ?

Answer (score 0):

The AOSP browser, and any WebView up to 4.3 cannot use CSS filter effect (see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)). You also cannot use SVG filter, since that is not supported either.

What you can do is using a Javascript image manipulation library, such as [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/)